# aiohttp/asyncio unexcepted running sequence results

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

```
import asyncio
import time

import aiohttp

now = lambda :time.time()
async def do_some_work(x):
    print("waiting:",x)
    await asyncio.sleep(x)
    return f"Web is ok"

start = now()
coroutine = do_some_work(2) # a future
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

task = asyncio.ensure_future(coroutine)
loop.run_until_complete(task)
print("In the process of accessing web") # I want this run first before sleep
print("Task ret:", task.result())
print("Time:", now() - start)
```

These are my results and question:

1. python3 test_aio_return.py
2. waiting: 2 (sleep here)
3. In the process of accessing web.
4. Task ret: `Web is ok`. I want it to sleep at this step as I'm using the result of the coroutine this line.
5. Time: 2.0011699199676514

Comment: what is the question? You should better describe problem.

Comment: if you want to run `print(...)` before `sleep()` then put it before `loop.run...`. OR you should run it as another task. because `run_until_complete` blocks other code `until complete tasks`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show my question explicitly. Yes I do want my `print` run before `sleep`, but I want to make `sleep` go first, then as the coroutine is sleeping, the process will be granted to the main thread, then it goes to `print("In the process of accessing web")` and I'm just wondering will the coroutine granted the processor to main thread when it's sleeping?

Comment: when you use `coroutine` then you have to other elements also run in `coroutine` - because `run_until_complete` is running all time and it can't run other code.

Answer (score 0):

If you run one `coroutine` (or rather `Task`) then main thread is running `loop` which blocks this thread and other code you have to run in other `coroutine` (or rather `Task`).

Something like this:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def do_some_work(x):
    print("[do_some_work] waiting:", x)
    await asyncio.sleep(x)
    print("[do_some_work] end")
    return "Web is ok"

async def other():
    #print("[other] In the process of accessing web")
    for x in range(10):
        print("[other]", x, "In the process of accessing web")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():
    # create two tasks
    #task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(do_some_work(5))
    #task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(other())
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(do_some_work(5))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(other())

    # run both tasks at the same time
    #await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)
    #await asyncio.wait([task1, task2])
    await task1
    await task2

    return task1.result()

# --- main ---

now = lambda:time.time()

start = now()

print('start loop')
#loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
#result = loop.run_until_complete(main())
result = asyncio.run(main())
print('stop loop')

print("result:", result)

end = now()

print("Time:", end - start)
```

It works with `gather(task1, task2)`, `wait([task1, task2])` or directly `task1, task2`

---

**EDIT:**

It will not run at the same time if you use `coroutines` instead of `Tasks`

```
async def main():
    # create two coroutines
    task1 = do_some_work(5)
    task2 = other()

    # run coroutines one-after-another
    await task1
    await task2

    return task1.result()
```

It will need `gather(task1, task2)`, `wait([task1, task2])` to create `Tasks`

```
async def main():
    task1 = do_some_work(5)
    task2 = other()

    results = await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)
    #print(results)

    return results[0]
```